# XSLT 1.0: Muenchian grouping does not work

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have the following simplified XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<list>
<INVOIC>
    <M_INVOIC>
        <G_SG25>
            <S_LIN>
                <id>LIN</id>
                <D_1082>1</D_1082>
                <C_C212>
                    <D_7140>7610400271943</D_7140>
                    <D_7143_3>EN</D_7143_3>
                </C_C212>
            </S_LIN>
        </G_SG25>
        <G_SG25>
            <S_LIN>
                <id>LIN</id>
                <D_1082>2</D_1082>
                <C_C212>
                    <D_7140>1234567890123</D_7140>
                    <D_7143_3>EN</D_7143_3>
                </C_C212>
            </S_LIN>
        </G_SG25>
    </M_INVOIC>
</INVOIC>
<INVOIC>
    <SALESORDER>
        <ET_VBAP>
            <item>
                <VBELN>0010002695</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                <MATNR>000000000000400487</MATNR>
                <EAN11>1234567890123</EAN11>
            </item>
            <item>
                <VBELN>0010002695</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                <MATNR>000000000000002054</MATNR>
                <EAN11>5012454920549</EAN11>
            </item>
            <item>
                <VBELN>0010002695</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
                <MATNR>000000000000392104</MATNR>
                <EAN11>3046920921046</EAN11>
            </item>
            <item>
                <VBELN>0010002695</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000040</POSNR>
                <MATNR>000000000000859146</MATNR>
                <EAN11>8003340591469</EAN11>
            </item>
            <item>
                <VBELN>0010002695</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000050</POSNR>
                <MATNR>000000000000727194</MATNR>
                <EAN11>7610400271943</EAN11>
            </item>
        </ET_VBAP>
    </SALESORDER>
</INVOIC>
</list>
```

my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kByEanPos" match="G_SG25" use="S_LIN/C_C212/D_7140"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    
    <xsl:variable name="uniqueSet" select="G_SG25[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kByEanPos',S_LIN/C_C212/D_7140))]"/>
    <list>
        <xsl:for-each select="list/INVOIC/M_INVOIC/G_SG25[generate-id()=
            generate-id(key('kByEanPos',S_LIN/C_C212/D_7140))]">
            <ean>
                <xsl:value-of select="parent::M_INVOIC/parent::INVOIC/parent::list/INVOIC/SALESORDER/ET_VBAP/item/MATNR"/>
            </ean>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </list>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives me this XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
<ean>000000000000400487</ean>
<ean>000000000000400487</ean>
</list>
```

But my expected XML output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
<ean>000000000000727194</ean>
<ean>000000000000400487</ean>
</list>
```

I am not sure of what I am doing wrong, I can't find my mistake. I think it has to do with the key that I defined.
Basically I need a key on `<D_7140>` and then look for that number in the structure below in `EAN11` and output the `MATNR` right before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to look up **item** elements based on their **EAN11** value, it might be worth considering using a key to do this too

```
<xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="EAN11" />
```

That way, you can reduce your **xsl:value-of** to just this

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('item', S_LIN/C_C212/D_7140)/MATNR"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
<xsl:value-of 
  select="parent::M_INVOIC/parent::INVOIC/parent::list/INVOIC/SALESORDER/ET_VBAP/item/MATNR"/>
```

You're climbing all the way up the node tree and back down to `MATNR`, so the only thing this is ever going to find is the first `MATNR` in the document.  To locate the `MATNR` that corresponds to the current `D_7140` in your `for-each`, this should work:

```
<xsl:value-of 
  select="/list/INVOIC/SALESORDER/ET_VBAP/item[EAN11 = current()/S_LIN/C_C212/D_7140]/MATNR"/>
```